# retail demo mode custom launcher

Tags: android, android-source, android-launcher, android-rom

I would like to create an application to change the retail demo mode video in a android retail device. Reference: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/display/retail-mode

Since the link leads to an aosp site, it seems to me that I have to modify the source code and create my own custom AOSP ROM. 
By adding a different launcher under packages/apps/RetailDemo I should be able to get a different video. 
I went into a few phone stores and saw that on stock android phones the retail demo app plays custom videos in the store but what if the targeted phone was running stock android?
Would the only way of changing the retail demo video on a stock android device be overwriting the phone's operating system with a AOSP android rom with a custom retail demo mode launcher? Or is there some easier way of implementing a custom retail demo mode video other than writing a custom AOSP android ROM?

Comment: What is the difference between vanilla Android and stock Android !?

Comment: Sorry about that I meant AOSP and stock. I have fixed the question. But what I mean is I would like to have a way for changing the video in the question and also leaving the operating system the same as the phone manufacturer meant it to be. This is a problem on some phones like sony for example, which comes with pre-installed apps.